# Hidden and cell state of Keras LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I would like to print out the hidden and cell state of Keras LSTM 
with `return_state = True`. For example, in the following, how can I 
print out `state_h` and `state_c`?

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1)) 
lstm1, state_h, state_c = LSTM(1, return_state=True)(inputs1)
```

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: Excuse me for asking - I don't know Keras - but don't you just need a `print` statement?

Comment: Yes, like @dash2 said - just use print.

Comment: it prints just a Tensor like  Tensor("lstm_36/while/Exit_2:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32), want to print the Tensor which is initialized. Thanks